# как запретить отправку форм, если не стоит checkbox false

Tags: javascript, post, формы, submit

Есть много страничный сайт, мне нужно запретить отправку форму, если не стоит checkbox false. Я перебираю все чекбоксы и проверяю из на checked, но такая проверка работает криво и не учитывает момент, когда пользователь нажал на чек. Как это исправить?

```
 `const sendForm = (state) => {
    const errorMessage = 'Что-то пошло не так...',
        loadMessage = 'Загружается...',
        successMessage = 'Спасибо! Мы скоро с вами свяжемся!',
        infoMessage = 'Необходимо подтвердить согласие на обработку данных';

    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    const phoneInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[placeholder="Ваш номер телефона..."]');
    const nameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[placeholder="Ваше имя..."]');
    const promoCode = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Промокод"]');
    const thanks = document.getElementById('thanks');
    const inputsCheck = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

   const statusMessage = document.createElement('div');
    statusMessage.innerHTML = statusMessage;
    statusMessage.style.cssText = 'font-size: 1rem';
    function checkInput() {
    inputsCheck.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.checked = false) {
            statusMessage.innerHTML = infoMessage;
            return false}
        })
    
    }
   
    forms.forEach(form => {
        form.setAttribute('data-calc', 'end');

if(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            // checkInput()
            event.preventDefault();

            form.appendChild(statusMessage);

            statusMessage.textContent = loadMessage;
            const formData = new FormData(form);
        
            if(form.getAttribute('data-calc') === 'end') {
                for(let key in state) {
                    formData.append(key, state[key]);
                }
            }
            statusMessage.textContent = loadMessage;
            postData(formData)
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.status !== 200) {throw new Error('status network not 200');}
                return response;
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                statusMessage.textContent = successMessage;
                thanks.style.display = "block";   
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                    statusMessage.textContent = errorMessage;
            })
        
    })
}
});


    const postData = (body) => {
        return fetch('./server.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });
    };
};


export default sendForm; 
`
```

Answer (score 1):

операторы сравнения в JS "=="  и "===" (для неравенств "!="  и "!==" ). А у вас присвоение в примере

```
    if(item.checked = false) { // вот здесь
        statusMessage.innerHTML = infoMessage;
        return false}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка в условии, используйте оператор строгого равенства:

```
if(item.checked === false) {
    statusMessage.innerHTML = infoMessage;
    return false}
})
```

`==` - Оператор равенства, проверяет равенство двух элементов без учета типа.

`===` - Оператор строгого равенства, проверяет равенство учитывая тип.

`!=` - Оператор не равно.

`!==` - Оператор строго не равно.